# Problem with get.gazebosim.org

Tags: gazebo-10

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I use the following command:
curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
I get the following error:
sh: 2: Syntax error: newline unexpected
Is this a server issue, or is there a different way I should go about getting this package?

UPDATE: It works now, must have been a server issue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24357/problem-with-get.gazebosim.org/) by [avroman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22743/avroman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The http://get.gazebosim.org endpoint was broken for a while, sorry about that. It should be working again now.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0